# jquery issue on checkboxes in multi column in table

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table (generated with ASP:Repeater control). I have 2 check box columns in the table. Both the columns have a Select All check box in the header. So when we check the Select All, all the check boxes in the respective columns should be checked(pretty usual stuff. So I have handled that). Now the issue is that, when I check/unchecked a check box in column_1XRow_1, then the check box in the column_2XRow_1 should get enabled & checked/disabled & unchecked.

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $ResubAllChkBx = $('.ResubAll :checkbox');
    var $ResubItmChkBx = $('.ResubItm :checkbox');
    var $LLLCAllChkBx = $('.LLLCAll :checkbox');
    var $LLLCItmChkBx = $('.LLLCItm :checkbox');

    $ResubAllChkBx.change(function() {
        Chk_UnChkResubAll();
    });

    function Chk_UnChkResubAll() {
        if ($ResubAllChkBx.is(':checked')) {
            $ResubItmChkBx.filter(function() { return !this.disabled; }).attr('checked', 'checked');//check only when enabled
        }
        else {
            $ResubItmChkBx.filter(function() { return !this.disabled; }).removeAttr('checked');//check only when enabled
        }
    }
});`
```

So essentially Re sub is Col1 & LLLC is Col2.

I did all this stuff in plain JS code, but due to the load on the page, I start seeing the JS error "A script on this page ......"

How do I play around the check/unchecked check boxes in col1 & col2? Please help. I need the code in jQuery.

Thanks
Bobbie

Comment: when you reload you should post the check value  get it from url or keep it hidden..btb what is the error

Comment: HI Zod, The JS error I get is "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you want to abort the script?" I'm using IE 8 standard mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following script to your jquery code...

```
$('.ResubItm :checkbox').on('change', function(){    
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).siblings('[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked','checked');
        })
    else
        $(this).siblings('[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked','');
        })
});


$('.LLLCItm :checkbox').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).siblings('[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked','checked');
        })
    else
        $(this).siblings('[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked','');
        })
});
```